# Add a bootstrap 3 tooltip to google maps API v3 marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I want to add a bootstrap tooltip to google map marker.

I cannot add HTML 5 atributes to it. So i tried to find the ID or class of the marker and adding the tooltip via javascript.
But, when I try to inspect the marker element using chrome tools the right click does not work  inside the map canvas.

How should I go forward with it? Can I assign a custom ID to my google map marker.?? Or any other possible way?

My Code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    if (POIMarker) {
        POIMarker.setMap(null);
    }
    POIMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: 'Double-Click me to feed information about this place',
        icon: 'Images/POIMarker.png'
    });
    POIMarker.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(POIMarker, 'dblclick');
    google.maps.event.addListener(POIMarker, 'dblclick', function (event) {
        $('#POIModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I stumbled on the exact same requirement and I'm stuck.

Comment: No, I havent found anything related to it till now :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really hacked way of doing it, which tracks the mouse position and then positions a Bootstrap tooltip where the mouse is when the google map event is triggered. You could modify it to show the modal instead of a tooltip or use the click event instead of mouseover/out, as needed.

See http://jsfiddle.net/6o33fx6L/

```
var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY
}, false);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (event) {

    $("#tt").css("left", mouse.x + "px").css("top", (mouse.y - 20) + "px").tooltip('show');
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function (event) {

    $("#tt").tooltip('hide');
});
```

This version swaps in the marker's title for the tooltip:

http://jsfiddle.net/6o33fx6L/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can asign more fields to the marker with this little snippet

```
marker.set("id", YOURVALUE);
```

I'd place this code in your function where you create your markers, because it will be called most likely within a `for` loop. So maybe you could just do something like

```
for(i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i)
{
    // create marker
    marker.set("id", i);
    //set marker to map
}
```

Access is easy, just do

```
marker.get('id');
```

This should do what you need do clearly identify certain markers

Comment: You are right.. But I want to handle marker as a DOM element.. Which cannot be done through this.. A boootstrap tooltip can only be applied to HTML elements not to map objects..

Comment: You can't handle the Marker as a DOM element because it's not a DOM element as far as i know. It's a JavaScript Object which will be rendered. Well, maybe there's something you can do with `shadowDOM`, but i've never worked with it.